# How to create simple SOAP request?

Tags: php, soap

I tried to create a SOAP request but could not succeed.
SOAP WADL url is http://www.mobipost.com.au/httpapi/Messaging.asmx?WSDL

AND request should be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthenticationHeader xmlns="http://messaging.mobipostapi.thirdscreen.com.au/">
      <UserName>SAMPLE_USER</UserName>
      <Password>SAMPLE_PASS</Password>
    </AuthenticationHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <SendSMSToContacts xmlns="http://messaging.mobipostapi.thirdscreen.com.au/">
      <oSMS>
        <MessageText>THIS IS MESSAGE</MessageText>
      </oSMS>
      <ContactIDs>
        <int>123456789</int>
        <int>987654321</int>
      </ContactIDs>
    </SendSMSToContacts>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried:

```
$url = 'http://www.mobipost.com.au/httpapi/Messaging.asmx?WSDL';
$client = new SoapClient($url);
$result = $client->AuthenticationHeader(array('UserName' => 'SAMPLE_USER','Password' => 'SAMPLE_PASS'));
$result = $client->SendSMSToContacts(array('MessageText' => 'THIS IS MESSAGE'));
$result = $client->ContactIDs(array('123456789', '987654321'));
```

But it shows Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("AuthenticationHeader") is not a valid method for this service in D:\xampp\htdocs\globalmobile\send_message_v2.php:26 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\globalmobile\send_message_v2.php(26): SoapClient->__call('AuthenticationH...', Array) #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\globalmobile\send_message_v2.php(26): SoapClient->AuthenticationHeader(Array) #2 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\globalmobile\send_message_v2.php on line 26
```

Can you please help me to create valid SOAP request to communicate with WSDL server.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are must be only one request, you send three.
You must create something like this:

1) Set header for authentication:

```
$auth = $auth = new SOAPAuth('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
$header = new SOAPHeader('urn:example.org/auth', 'AuthenticationHeader', $auth);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

2) Create create request with message text and contacts.

```
$result = $client->SendSMSToContacts(array("MessageText" => "some text", "contactIDs" => array(123456789, 123456789));
```

P.S. For the debugging create client with:

```
$client = new SoapClient($url, array('trace' => 1,
            'exceptions' => 1,));
```

and after sending request, look on request that was sended and resopnse on it:

```
var_dump("REQUEST=", $client->__getLastRequest());
var_dump("RESPONSE=", $client->__getLastResponse());
```